Litespeed Enterprise issue with PHP83
As described in this Litespeed forum
We are trying to switch from Nginx + Varnish to litespeed so we can test litespeed cache with a magento 2.4.7 store. No panels. Just OS ubuntu 20.
Web server is installed, php83 compiled:
'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/lsws/lsphp8' '--with-mysqli' '--with-zlib' '--enable-gd' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-iconv' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--enable-ftp' '--with-zip' '--with-curl' '--enable-soap' '--enable-xml' '--with-openssl' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-intl' '--enable-apcu' '--with-imagick' '--enable-imap' '--enable-redis' '--enable-memcached' '--enable-msgpack' '--with-ldap' '--with-snmp' '--with-sqlite3' '--with-pspell' '--with-ioncube' '--with-pgsql' '--with-tidy' '--enable-litespeed'

Vhost is temporary fixed.
Web server is running as user: nobody, group: nogroup. And magento is running with its own user. Litespeed have permissions in all folders.
Problem is that we cannot configure php83 with needed modules to run our php platform
We get strange errors like:
Exception #0 (Laminas\Captcha\Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException): Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support

It seems that this error is coming from phpGD which is already there
Our magento is latest version and it compatible with php8.3. Needs these modules to run:
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
igbinary
imagick
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mailparse
mbstring
mcrypt
msgpack
mysqli
mysqlnd
newrelic
OAuth
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
pspell
random
raphf
readline
redis
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
ssh2
standard
swoole
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
yaml
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache


Is Litespeed web server compatible, because I dont understand why php has issues?
What am I missing and cannot compile php83 the right way?

